# Low score and wrong answer for Flan-T5-XXL "question-answering" task

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm trying to run Flan-T5-XXL model for a "question-answering" task.
Here's how I loaded and executed the model:

```
model_id = "~/Downloads/test_LLM/flan-t5-xxl"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_id, return_dict=False).to(DEVICE)

qa_T5XXL = pipeline("question-answering", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

question = "What is 42?"
context = "42 is the answer to life, the universe and everything"

result = qa_T5XXL({
    "question": question,
    "context": context
})
```

However, I get a low score and a wrong answer:

```
{'score': 0.03840925544500351, 'start': 0, 'end': 2, 'answer': '42'}
```

Could you please help me make changes to achieve the correct answer?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Pre/Script:** This is more of a science experiment design or product development question than a programming question, so most probably someone will flag to close this question on Stackoverflow eventually. But here's an attempt to answer.

## In Short

There is a couple of things to consider before someone can help to answer the question.

- What is ultimate goal of getting the answers right?
- How do you determine what is the right answers?
- How do you measure what is right? Is there a metric you use? Or a fix test dataset of question, context, answer triplets?

## In Long

Here's a few QnA to clarify somethings about LLM and QnA.

### Q: What does the "start" and "end" mean in the results?

A: Given these,

[in]:

```
question = "What is 42?"
context = "42 is the answer to life, the universe and everything"
```

[out]:

```
results = {'score': 0.03840925544500351, 'start': 0, 'end': 2, 'answer': '42'}
```

We see the "start" and "end" indices. That indicates that the model you are using is an extractive QnA system, i.e. given a question and context find the answer inside the context string.

So, the "answer" in the result dictionary is:

```
context[results['start']:result['end']  # i.e. "42"
```

### Q: Then, what does the "score" mean in the results?

A: From https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/pipelines/question_answering.py#L46, we see:

```py
def decode_spans(
    start: np.ndarray, end: np.ndarray, topk: int, max_answer_len: int, undesired_tokens: np.ndarray
) -> Tuple:
    """
    Take the output of any `ModelForQuestionAnswering` and will generate probabilities for each span to be the actual
    answer.

    In addition, it filters out some unwanted/impossible cases like answer len being greater than max_answer_len or
    answer end position being before the starting position. The method supports output the k-best answer through the
    topk argument.

    Args:
        start (`np.ndarray`): Individual start probabilities for each token.
        end (`np.ndarray`): Individual end probabilities for each token.
        topk (`int`): Indicates how many possible answer span(s) to extract from the model output.
        max_answer_len (`int`): Maximum size of the answer to extract from the model's output.
        undesired_tokens (`np.ndarray`): Mask determining tokens that can be part of the answer
    """
    # Ensure we have batch axis
    if start.ndim == 1:
        start = start[None]

    if end.ndim == 1:
        end = end[None]

    # Compute the score of each tuple(start, end) to be the real answer
    outer = np.matmul(np.expand_dims(start, -1), np.expand_dims(end, 1))

    # Remove candidate with end < start and end - start > max_answer_len
    candidates = np.tril(np.triu(outer), max_answer_len - 1)

    #  Inspired by Chen & al. (https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA)
    scores_flat = candidates.flatten()
    if topk == 1:
        idx_sort = [np.argmax(scores_flat)]
    elif len(scores_flat) < topk:
        idx_sort = np.argsort(-scores_flat)
    else:
        idx = np.argpartition(-scores_flat, topk)[0:topk]
        idx_sort = idx[np.argsort(-scores_flat[idx])]

    starts, ends = np.unravel_index(idx_sort, candidates.shape)[1:]
    desired_spans = np.isin(starts, undesired_tokens.nonzero()) & np.isin(ends, undesired_tokens.nonzero())
    starts = starts[desired_spans]
    ends = ends[desired_spans]
    scores = candidates[0, starts, ends]

    return starts, ends, scores
```

#### Q: Showing `np.matmul(np.expand_dims(start, -1), np.expand_dims(end, 1))` doesn't tell me anything about what the scores mean... What happens when we allow more than 1 answers?

`flan-t5-xxl` is too big demonstrate the results, so lets try tiny,

```
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline("question-answering", model="google/flan-t5-small")

question = "What is 42?"
context = "42 is the answer to life, the universe and everything"

result = pipe({
    "question": question,
    "context": context
}, top_k=5)
```

[out]:

```
[{'score': 0.011151721701025963, 'start': 25, 'end': 29, 'answer': ' the'},
 {'score': 0.01089030597358942,
  'start': 5,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' the answer to life, the'},
 {'score': 0.0108568724244833,
  'start': 0,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': '42 is the answer to life, the'},
 {'score': 0.010814748704433441,
  'start': 16,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' to life, the'},
 {'score': 0.01060018502175808,
  'start': 19,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' life, the'}]
```

#### Q: Linda umzuzu! (Wait a minute!), does that mean it will compute possibilities of any possible span within the context?

Yes, kinda! That's the goal of extractive QnA. The answer is in the context, the brute force way is to score all possible spans to get the best answer. The `top_k` argument controls how many candidates to consider.

```
question = "What is 42?"
context = "42 is the answer to life, the universe and everything"

result = pipe({
    "question": question,
    "context": context
}, top_k=30)
```

[out]:

```
[{'score': 0.011151721701025963, 'start': 25, 'end': 29, 'answer': ' the'},
 {'score': 0.01089030597358942,
  'start': 5,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' the answer to life, the'},
 {'score': 0.0108568724244833,
  'start': 0,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': '42 is the answer to life, the'},
 {'score': 0.010814748704433441,
  'start': 16,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' to life, the'},
 {'score': 0.01060018502175808,
  'start': 19,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' life, the'},
 {'score': 0.010392689146101475,
  'start': 19,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' life, the'},
 {'score': 0.010242749936878681,
  'start': 9,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' answer to life, the'},
 {'score': 0.009692603722214699,
  'start': 5,
  'end': 16,
  'answer': ' the answer'},
 {'score': 0.00966284703463316,
  'start': 0,
  'end': 16,
  'answer': '42 is the answer'},
 {'score': 0.009410168044269085,
  'start': 2,
  'end': 29,
  'answer': ' is the answer to life, the'},
 {'score': 0.00911626499146223, 'start': 9, 'end': 16, 'answer': ' answer'},
 {'score': 0.00905834324657917,
  'start': 25,
  'end': 38,
  'answer': ' the universe'},
 {'score': 0.008912604302167892,
  'start': 29,
  'end': 38,
  'answer': ' universe'},
 {'score': 0.008845999836921692,
  'start': 5,
  'end': 38,
  'answer': ' the answer to life, the universe'},
 {'score': 0.008818842470645905,
  'start': 0,
  'end': 38,
  'answer': '42 is the answer to life, the universe'},
 {'score': 0.008786008693277836,
  'start': 38,
  'end': 53,
  'answer': ' and everything'},
 {'score': 0.008784625679254532,
  'start': 16,
  'end': 38,
  'answer': ' to life, the universe'},
 {'score': 0.00861033983528614,
  'start': 19,
  'end': 38,
  'answer': ' life, the universe'},
 {'score': 0.008441794663667679,
  'start': 19,
  'end': 38,
  'answer': ' life, the universe'},
 {'score': 0.008398951031267643, 'start': 0, 'end': 5, 'answer': '42 is'},
 {'score': 0.008392956107854843,
  'start': 5,
  'end': 25,
  'answer': ' the answer to life,'},
 {'score': 0.008388272486627102, 'start': 5, 'end': 9, 'answer': ' the'},
 {'score': 0.008375249803066254,
  'start': 2,
  'end': 16,
  'answer': ' is the answer'},
 {'score': 0.008367189206182957,
  'start': 0,
  'end': 25,
  'answer': '42 is the answer to life,'},
 {'score': 0.008362519554793835, 'start': 0, 'end': 9, 'answer': '42 is the'},
 {'score': 0.00833472516387701, 'start': 16, 'end': 25, 'answer': ' to life,'},
 {'score': 0.00832000095397234,
  'start': 9,
  'end': 38,
  'answer': ' answer to life, the universe'},
 {'score': 0.008312774822115898,
  'start': 25,
  'end': 53,
  'answer': ' the universe and everything'},
 {'score': 0.00820864923298359,
  'start': 42,
  'end': 53,
  'answer': ' everything'},
 {'score': 0.008179032243788242,
  'start': 29,
  'end': 53,
  'answer': ' universe and everything'}]
```

#### Q: Does that mean that I'll not always get the right answer?

A: Yes, correct. LLM or pre-trained models are tuned to whatever the data is.

First, we have to ask:

- **What exactly is the desired answer?**

  - In the context of your question, I guess you are expecting "the answer to life, the universe and everything"
  - But consider the valid statement of a tautology, "X is X", so the answer "42 is 42" is a valid for the "What is 42?" question.

Next, we need to ask:

- Does the training data use to fine-tune or train the model contains the expected behavior?
- Or does it contain tautology such that the model learns to emulate that during inference?

Given that for most models you'll see in the wild, it's hard to determine the above questions, your next practical question would be:

### Q: Okay, so no model is perfect. How do I make the model output what I need?

A: First, you'll need to consider,

- Is the pre-trained model you chosen tuned our your task or domain? Question and Answer is a very wide task, knowing how to answer on stackoverflow don't make you an expert on answering legal questions or pop-culture questions.
- Have you fine-tuned the model to your task or domain? Did it perform better than the original pre-trained model?

Then you need to consider:

- Does one failed inference instance affect the system you want to build? What is the "fidelity" of the system you are building? E.g. if it's a medical domain, would you kill someone if the model answer wrongly?
- How exactly is the model going to be deployed and how you want to measure the success?

  - Is it just based on (i) random anecdotal examples, or (ii) is there a specific metric that the model should improve towards?

    - if (i), do you have a large enough sample of anecdotes examples to test on?
    - if (ii), would you be able to overlook the fact that the score outperforms the original pre-trained model but fail on some anecdotal examples.

### Q: Yeah, yeah, I know all you are insinuating but I just want to %^&*-ing solve this question to give the right answer?

A: Consider, some business logic. Many a times, big tech handles common Q with manually edited A. Using that you need to fine-tune the model or using some caching mechanism to achieve the desired result if you dont want to spend time/effort re-training / fine-tuning the model.

i.e.

```
if "question" == "What is 42?"
    result = {"answer": "answer to life, the universe and everything"}
else:
    result = qa_T5XXL({
    "question": question,
    "context": context
})
```

For reference, see:

- [Parsing city of origin / destination city from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956670/parsing-city-of-origin-destination-city-from-a-string)
- https://hackernoon.com/tmnt-translation-memory-and-neural-translation

### Q: I don't want to have any rule-base, just tell me how to hack the code to get the right answer already.

A: You will most probably not get the right answer in the top-1 answer easily. You have to manage the noise in the top_k outputs and try to extend the candidate possibilities to everything possible in the context, e.g.

```
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline("question-answering", model="google/flan-t5-small")

question = "What is 42?"
context = "42 is the answer to life, the universe and everything"

result = pipe({
    "question": question,
    "context": context
}, top_k=500, max_answer_len=len(context))

which_rank = [(i,r) for i, r in enumerate(result) if r['answer'].strip() == "the answer to life, the universe and everything"]
```

[out]:

```
[(34,
  {'score': 0.008117909543216228,
   'start': 5,
   'end': 53,
   'answer': ' the answer to life, the universe and everything'})]
```

Voila, the right answer is ranked 34 out of 500!

#### Q: But that is meaningless, I want it to be the top answer. If not, how do I evaluate how good the model is?

A: Now, that is a good question. If you have a test set with the right answers and you are not getting the right answers in the top-1 or even top-10 candidates. You might need to reconsider how you evaluate the model.

Depending on the ultimate goal,

- if the goal is to improve the model until the correct answer goes up to the top-1, then consider evaluating the model in terms of rank reciprocal, e.g. MRR, NDCG, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#label-ranking-average-precision
- if the goal is to just make sure that the model works off-the-shelf, then I'll consider more customized solutions, e.g.

  - pay more for better closed-APIs that has a service level agreement you can negotiate to get the right answers you want, or
  - somehow get some service to train/fine-tune the model
  - try prompt engineering for "one-shot", "few-shot" learning, if you google around these days, there should be quite a lot to advise how to go around that, e.g. https://www.deeplearning.ai/short-courses/chatgpt-prompt-engineering-for-developers/
- if the goal is to ultimately get a model with that correctly answers on any questions you have in mind, and you have the compute, human and time resources, consider fine-tuning the model on relevant domain data, then re-evaluate the accuracy score, with something like `seqeval` or rogue scores.

Comment: Thank you very much for this well-detailed answer.
To be transparent, my end goal is to extract specific pieces of information from a dataset. These pieces of information are actually the serial number and the manufacturer of hardware in different texts placed in random places in the text. And before I try to go deep into these LLM models I wanted to try and ask it to get me the informations. I wanted to test them on easy data and see how it goes. My first thought was that these models are well-tuned already so they would do well with easy examples like the one I gave...

Comment: Glad the answer helps. Just a note, this is usually not the kind of questions that folks encourage or answer on Stackoverflow. Others might flag the question as 'need clarity' and close it.

Comment: Opinion: No model is well tuned or trained for anything other than the data they are trained on. No free lunch. Models can have some "emergent" abilities on things they are not trained on, but definitely inadequate realistically for anything more than whatever data/domain they are trained on.

Comment: Answer looks great, but it does not appear to follow the SO standard (you are answering a lot of questions in one answer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer =)